# How to retrieve value of parameters annotated by @RequestBody from a HttpServeletRequest object?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, netflix-zuul

in a springcloud project
if a backend microservice has the following:

```
@RequestMapping("/test")
pubilc void test(@RequestBody MyPram myParam){
    ...
}
```

how can I retrive the "myParam" value in a zuul filter?
in other words, since I can have the following code segment in a zuul filter

```
    RequestContext ctx = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = ctx.getRequest();
```

how can I  retrive the "myParam" value  from a request?

Comment: You cannot as Zuul knows nothing about that.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know in Spring Cloud but tried in springMVC (spring version 3) we can get the Request body HttpServeletRequest object or method.

@RequestMapping(value="/employee/{id}")
    public @ResponseBody String demo(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("id") Integer id) {

```
    if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("POST")) {
        return "POST MEhod";
    } else if (request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("GET")) {
        return "GET Method";
     }
      }
```

Its not exact what you are looking but it will give you hint to solve your problem